# select where (column defined as) or count(*) > 50 something like that

Tags: mysql, where-clause

This mysql query gives me unknown column error

```
SELECT count(vs.no) AS no_of_vocabs, level, owner_no FROM vocab_stats as vs 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT no, level FROM mst_words) mw ON mw.no = vs.vocab_no 
WHERE owner_no = 6 AND correct > 0 AND vs.no_of_vocabs > 50 
group by owner_no, level
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: mind to indicate which column is **unknown**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `HAVING` (see [documentation on SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html))

```
SELECT COUNT(vs.no), level, owner_no FROM vocab_stats as vs 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT no, level FROM mst_words) mw ON mw.no = vs.vocab_no 
WHERE owner_no = 6 AND correct > 0
GROUP BY owner_no, level
HAVING COUNT(vs.no) > 50
```

Comment: Maybe your LEFT JOIN can be simplified too

Comment: Can you advise how this worked when you have included vs.no_of_vocabs, which was defined before as COUNT(vs.no). What was the unknown column from before as this doesn't seem to be a proper fix.

Comment: it worked with a few fixes, sorry I forgot to include. 
What would you suggest to simplify the LEFT JOIN? Thank you

Comment: Maybe your join is equivalent to `LEFT JOIN mst_words AS mw ON mw.no = vs.vocab_no`

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the unknown column is `vs.no_of_vocabs` as you have defined `no_of_vocabs` but it is not part of the `vs`/`vocab_stats` table, it's just part of the query. Remove the `vs` from `vs.no_of_vocabs` and it should be fixed.

If this is not the problem we would need to see the error message.